# C++ is there another way to access members first and second than using a range for loop for std::vector <std::pair <int, int>>?

Tags: c++, stdvector, std-pair

I solved another problem the other day involving a `std::vector <std::pair<int,int>>` called `name`.

My question is, how do I access the `name.first` and `name.second` of this type?

I ended up using a ranged-for loop, that solved my issue

```cpp
for(i : name) { i->first , i->second}
```

But, is there another way? I am particularly interested in how to access this in a normal `for` loop, e.g

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) { std::vector::std::pair::name.first}
```

Can anybody shed some light on this for me?

Comment: a vector has no `first` or `second`, the vectors elements do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)
{
     cout << name[i].first;
     cout << name[i].second;
}
```

This is just the typical way to access a vector (or array) of structs.

BTW the code you said worked in fact does not, `for(i : name) { i->first , i->second}` should be `for(i : name) { i.first , i.second}`. Your version would work for a vector of pair pointers, but not for a vector of pairs.

Comment: I might remember wrong, I wrote this off my head, but thank you for clarifying.

Comment: `for(i : name)` should be `for(auto &i : name)`. You need to declare the type for `i`, unless it has already been declared earlier. And you don't want to access copies of the pairs, you want to access the original pairs.

Answer (score 5):

In C++17, you can use a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

```
for (auto & [a, b] : name) {
    // a is a reference to the first of each pair
    // b is a reference to the second of each pair
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++17 (or greater) Structure Bindings can do this

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector <std::pair<int,int>> vp;

    for (auto & [first,second] : vp)
    {
        // do something with first and second
    };
}
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Answer (score 2):

As of C++17, you can use [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> v{};
    v.push_back({1, 11});
    v.push_back({2, 22});
    for (auto [a, b] : v) {
        std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";   
    }  // 1 11
       // 2 22
}
```

Note that `auto` in the structured binding declaration means each pair is taken by value (which is reasonable when working with fundamental types).

If you want to either read a non-fundamental type, or write via structured binding identifier, you may use `auto const&` or `auto&`, respectively. E.g.:

```
// add 'first' to 'second;
for (auto& [a, b] : v) {
    b += a;  
}  // 1 11
   // 2 22

// read only (by value)
for (auto [a, b] : v) {
    std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";   
}  // 1 12
   // 2 24
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> somePairs{ {1, 2}, {5, 10}, {12, 60} };

    for (auto [first, second] : somePairs)
    {
        std::cout << "First = " << first << ", second = " << second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This automatically unpacks the `std::pair`s inside the `std::vector` into the `first` and `second` variables.

Output:

```
First = 1, second = 2
First = 5, second = 10
First = 12, second = 60
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic question about C++ syntax. I recommend a book instead of Stack Overflow.

The elegant way to do this is:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> names;
for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    auto &name = names[i];
    // now access name.first, name.second
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
unordered_map<int , int> mp;
for(auto x:mp)
{

    cout<<x.first;
    cout<<x.second;
}
```

This is the way you can access members first and second in a standard template library (STL) by creating a container with key-value and a mapped value with unique pair.